# Temporal Neo4J database for "data masking"

Tags: design-patterns, neo4j, graph-databases, temporal-database, data-masking

I'm evaluating databases for a project.  Right now I'm strongly preferring Neo4J for it's graph nature.

I'm looking to create a temporal database that uses something like a "last good value" approach (my words).

Here's an example using a rough Neo4J pseudo-code.  Imagine the following happening as separate transactions.

```
CREATE (a:Person {first: "Charles", last: "Tolliver", timestamp: timestamp() + 00})
CREATE (b:Person {first: "Charlie",                   timestamp: timestamp() + 10})
CREATE (c:Person {first: "Chuck",                     timestamp: timestamp() + 20})
CREATE (d:Person {                  last: "Peters",   timestamp: timestamp() + 30})
CREATE (e:Person {age:42,                             timestamp: timestamp() + 40})

CREATE (a)<-[:UPDATES]-(b)<-[:UPDATES]-(c)<-[:UPDATES]-(d)<-[:UPDATES]-(e)
RETURN a,b,c,d,e;
```

Then I want to be able to do something like:

```
MATCH (p:Person)
WHERE p.first="Charles"
return p, collect( 
  { first: p.first, last: p.last, age: p.age, timestamp: p.timestamp }
)
```

I would like to get data back like this:

```
{ first: "Chuck", last: "Peters, age: 42, timestamp:...}
```

Where each subsequent insert "masks" the prior data.

Ideally I'd like to be able to query in the same manner with a variety of timestamps and get "snapshot" of the aggregate object at that point in time.

Questions:

- Does this pattern have a name I can research?
- Are there any databases that support this pattern natively/out-of-the-box?
- Is there a clean paradigm/tool set for this in Neo4J or another graph db?

*Note:  For various reasons, I prefer not to use a 'frame'-based temporality.

*Note:  I am not asking "Which databases are 'best' for this" or anything subjective.  I'm looking for objective info about support for this pattern/paradigm.*

Comment: Are you looking to do a kind of time-based versioning of the graph? If so, Ian Robinson wrote an excellent blog post on how one might do that. http://iansrobinson.com/2014/05/13/time-based-versioned-graphs/

Comment: It sounds like the prototypal inheritance or instance inheritance of `Self` and `JavaScript`, is that what you have in mind? Not sure what the best way to implement that would be, and it might be easier to do as an application layer than entirely modelling it in the database. One method would be to store a linked list of versions, retrieve a sublist to some depth, and for each property retrieval traverse the sublist from tail to head and return the first instance of the property.

Comment: Thanks; I'll take a look at the article, Kenny Bastani.

I think the JavaScript paradigm inspires what I mean.  I am investigating "Datomic" by Cognitect as a possible solution for this.  I'll post back if I find anything satisfactory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up going with Datomic because of the built-in temporality.  I'm enjoying it a lot (especially Datalog, it's query language).  I do wish it had more practical documentation, though.

Comment: We're open to receiving specific requests to improve documentation - feel free to provide any in the [Datomic group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/datomic)